# How to read response body from NodeJs http proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I'm trying to create a simple http proxy with nodejs, and i want to read the response body.

I created the proxy and it works but the problem that i'm facing is that when ever i try to console log the response body it just shows "��@�^j�J��tu7��X��ZgG���cb��ܩ", i tried the example given in the node-http-proxy documentation it works but it show the same output it doesn't output as text.

This is the code i'm using :

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var urlObj = url.parse(req.url);
    var target = urlObj.protocol + "//" + urlObj.host;
    var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

    res.oldWrite = res.write;
    res.write = function(data) {
        //this doesn't output text
        console.log(data.toString('UTF8'));
        res.oldWrite(data);
    }
    proxy.web(req, res, {target: target});

}).listen(8080);
```

EDIT:
If any one is having the same issue it was that the request was encoded with GZIP (you will find a header 'Content-encoding' ), you can just decode it and read it as plain text.

Comment: That was a useful question, saved me some time - I was wondering why the response body looked like that!

Comment: You should only make a single proxy instance, outside of `http.createServer`. No need to create a new one inside each http handler.